# How to stop mobile version of website showing in google?

Tags: html, css, mobile, desktop

We have a website that has both a mobile and desktop version. Its not responsive in the way that desktop browser can be re-sized and all content is responsive. Basically 2 separate versions for desktop and mobile.

When we search for the site in google, the results are too the mobile version of the site, even when searching on desktop.

Obviously the mobile version looks terrible on desktop, so can you please tell me how this is happening and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: maybe this can help https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls?hl=en

Comment: You want to hide Mobile Version in google search result? it have different url? so you can block agents and spiders via robot.txt and demote urls in google webmasters.

Answer (score 1):

You can place robot.txt file in root mobile directory with text:
"Disallow: /[your's mobile page link].htm"